# Parsing Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, nginx

Update 1:
As requested with this code I get

```
<?php
require_once 'Conf.php';
use Nemiro\Nginx\Conf as NginxConf;
$conf = new NginxConf('/etc/nginx/sites-available/proxy');

echo '<pre>'.var_dump($conf['server']['server_name']->ParametersAsString()).'</pre><br>';
echo '<pre>'.var_dump($conf['server']['location']).'</pre>';
?>
```

I get

> string(9) "localhost"
>
> object(Nemiro\Nginx\Directive)#8 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(8) "location"
>   ["Parameters"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "/" } ["Directives"]=>
>   object(Nemiro\Nginx\DirectiveCollection)#9 (1) { ["Items"]=> array(1)
>   { ["proxy_pass"]=> object(Nemiro\Nginx\Directive)#10 (3) { ["Name"]=>
>   string(10) "proxy_pass" ["Parameters"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(19)
>   "http://127.0.0.1:80" } ["Directives"]=>
>   object(Nemiro\Nginx\DirectiveCollection)#11 (1) { ["Items"]=> array(0)
>   { } } } } } }

But how do I only extract, "localhost" and like "proxy_pass" and such? Thank you so much!

---

So I have this array right now

```
object(Nemiro\Nginx\Directive)#2 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(6) "server"
["Parameters"]=> NULL ["Directives"]=>
object(Nemiro\Nginx\DirectiveCollection)#3 (1) { ["Items"]=> array(3)
{ ["listen"]=> object(Nemiro\Nginx\Directive)#4 (3) { ["Name"]=>
string(6) "listen" ["Parameters"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "80" }
["Directives"]=> object(Nemiro\Nginx\DirectiveCollection)#5 (1) {
["Items"]=> array(0) { } } } ["server_name"]=>
object(Nemiro\Nginx\Directive)#6 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(11)
"server_name" ["Parameters"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "localhost"
} ["Directives"]=> object(Nemiro\Nginx\DirectiveCollection)#7 (1) {
["Items"]=> array(0) { } } } ["location"]=>
object(Nemiro\Nginx\Directive)#8 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(8) "location"
["Parameters"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "/" } ["Directives"]=>
object(Nemiro\Nginx\DirectiveCollection)#9 (1) { ["Items"]=> array(1)
{ ["proxy_pass"]=> object(Nemiro\Nginx\Directive)#10 (3) { ["Name"]=>
string(10) "proxy_pass" ["Parameters"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(19)
"http://127.0.0.1:80" } ["Directives"]=>
 object(Nemiro\Nginx\DirectiveCollection)#11 (1) { ["Items"]=> array(0)
{ } } } } } } } } } 80string(9) "localhost"
```

That is done by calling

```
var_dump($conf['server']);

if ($conf['server']->ContainsChild('listen'))
{
  print_r($conf['server']['listen']->ParametersAsString());
}

var_dump($conf['server']['server_name']->ParametersAsString());
var_dump($conf['server']['root']->ParametersAsString());
var_dump($conf['server']['location']);
```

What would I have to do if I wanted to call for example "http://127.0.0.1:80" without showing anything else? So it would be like

```
echo $conf['server']['location']['proxy_passs']
```

but the above doesn't work? Any ideas?

I uploaded the code online on Github, the parser is not my code. I'm trying to use it, it allows me to edit nginx files easily, if you find better code please tell me

https://github.com/chessboardthedev/Parser

Comment: The dump you have is an object, put <pre> around it and that'll make it easier to read

Comment: That's not an array. It's an object.

Comment: If all you want is the actual localhost address/ domain name you don't need to dump all those other objects. You only need one of the last two: var_dump($conf['server']['root']->ParametersAsString()); or var_dump($conf['server']['location']); Try dumping those and posting it here. You just need to call the right objects and you'll get that out easy.

Answer (score 0):

I got to work with this

```
echo $conf['server']['location']['proxy_pass']['0'];
```

to output

> http://127.0.0.1:80

from

> object(Nemiro\Nginx\Directive)#8 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(8) "location" ["Parameters"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "/" } ["Directives"]=> object(Nemiro\Nginx\DirectiveCollection)#9 (1) { ["Items"]=> array(1) { ["proxy_pass"]=> object(Nemiro\Nginx\Directive)#10 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(10) "proxy_pass" ["Parameters"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(19) "http://127.0.0.1:80" } ["Directives"]=> object(Nemiro\Nginx\DirectiveCollection)#11 (1) { ["Items"]=> array(0) { } } } } } }

Thank you :)